# Getting a certain element from XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, xml-parsing

I have a following XML file to parse:

```
<result>
<iban>GB20ULSB98006054100029</iban>
<account>54100029</account>
<sort_code>980060</sort_code>
<bank>ULSTER BANK LTD</bank>
<branch>BELFAST CITY OFFICE 1</branch>
<bic>ULSBGB2BXXX</bic>
<address>PO BOX 232 11-16 DONEGALL SQUARE EAST </address>
<city>BT1 5UB</city>
<country>GB<country/>
<phone>028 90244112</phone>
</result>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to get an element 'iban'?

Comment: What had you tried so far?

Comment: Privacy? What's this "privacy" you are talking about? I am just sharing data, why should that violate someones "privacy"?

Comment: So far I have tried to parse it using the XDocument library, however I don't know how to get just a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `XDocument`, you can read the elements

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
var iban = xdoc.Element("result").Element("iban").Value;
```